# Iterating over a tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, stl

I tried to write a small header-only library that provides a type similar to iterators for `std::tuple` as well as some STL-like algorithms. I would be grateful for your comments and suggestions.

Code on GitHub: https://github.com/Nicholas42/Cpp-Bits-and-Pieces/tree/master/tup_iter

```cpp
// tup_iter.hpp
#ifndef TUP_ITER_HPP
#define TUP_ITER_HPP

#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

namespace tuple_iter {

// Tag objects to enable deduction of index
template<size_t Index>
inline constexpr std::integral_constant<size_t, Index> index_tag;

template<class Tup, size_t Index>
struct TupleIter {
    using tuple_t = Tup;

    explicit TupleIter(tuple_t &t) : tup(t) {}

    TupleIter(tuple_t &t, std::integral_constant<size_t, Index> /*unused*/) : tup(t) {}

    // BEGIN - Static Method Section

    static constexpr auto size() noexcept -> size_t {
        return std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<tuple_t>>;
    }

    static constexpr auto index() noexcept -> size_t {
        return Index;
    }

    template<class Inp>
    static constexpr decltype(auto) get(Inp &&inp) {
        if constexpr (Index < size()) {
            return std::get<Index>(inp);
        } else {
            // Improves error messages.
            static_assert(Index < size(), "Enditerator is not dereferencable.");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // END - Static Method Section

  private:
    tuple_t &tup;

    // Helper for value_t since we cannot specialize a type alias directly and have to prevent the
    // instantiation of std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple_t> for the case of I == size() sinze then this
    // would not compile. Hence, we cannot simply use std::conditional.

    // value_t for the past-the-end iterator
    template<size_t I = Index, class = void>
    struct helper_struct {
        struct incomplete;
        using value_type = incomplete;   // Wanted to take void, but then references do not compile even
                                         // if in SFINAE-deactivated functions.
        using next_type = incomplete;
    };

    // value_t for all dereferencable iterators
    template<size_t I>
    struct helper_struct<I, std::enable_if_t<(I < size())>> {
        using value_type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::decay_t<tuple_t>>;
        using next_type = TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + 1>;
    };

  public:
    // Return value of dereferencing operator
    using value_t = typename helper_struct<>::value_type;
    using next_t = typename helper_struct<>::next_type;

    // Comparison methods. Compare equal to objects of the same type (i.e. have same index are over same
    // tuple type)

    constexpr auto operator==([[maybe_unused]] const TupleIter<tuple_t, Index> &other) const noexcept
        -> bool {
        return true;
    }

    template<size_t I, class = std::enable_if_t<I != Index>>
    constexpr auto operator==([[maybe_unused]] const TupleIter<tuple_t, I> &other) const noexcept
        -> bool {
        return false;
    }

    template<size_t I>
    constexpr auto operator!=(const TupleIter<tuple_t, I> &other) const noexcept -> bool {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    // Canonical way to convert to bool, false iff past-the-end-iterator.

    constexpr explicit operator bool() const noexcept {
        return Index < size();
    }

    // These seem a bit weird since they are const de-/increment operators. But we cannot implement
    // operator+(int inc) as one would normally do it, since inc had to be a constant expression. So
    // this seems like the best way to do this. Furthermore it is actually similar to normal iterators,
    // since for them the following would be equivalent:
    //      ++it;       AND       it = ++it;
    // So reassigning the return value is not that weird.

    template<size_t I = Index, class = std::enable_if_t<(0 < I)>>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator--() const noexcept -> TupleIter<tuple_t, Index - 1> {
        return TupleIter<tuple_t, Index - 1>{tup};
    }

    template<size_t I = Index, class = std::enable_if_t<(I < size())>>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator++() const noexcept -> TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + 1> {
        return TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + 1>{tup};
    }

    template<std::ptrdiff_t N>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto advance() const noexcept -> TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + N> {
        return TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + N>{tup};
    }

    template<size_t I = Index, class = std::enable_if_t<(I < size())>>
    constexpr auto operator*() noexcept -> value_t & {
        return std::get<Index>(tup);
    }

    template<size_t I = Index, class = std::enable_if_t<(I < size())>>
    constexpr auto operator*() const noexcept -> const value_t & {
        return std::get<Index>(tup);
    }

    template<size_t I = Index, class = std::enable_if_t<(I < size())>>
    constexpr explicit operator value_t() const {
        return std::get<index()>(tup);
    }

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto get_tuple() const noexcept -> const tuple_t & {
        return tup;
    }

    constexpr auto get_tuple() noexcept -> tuple_t & {
        return tup;
    }
};

template<size_t Index, class Tuple>
TupleIter(Tuple, std::integral_constant<size_t, Index>)->TupleIter<Tuple, Index>;

namespace detail {
template<class T>
struct is_tuple_iter_impl : std::false_type {};

template<class Tup, size_t Index>
struct is_tuple_iter_impl<TupleIter<Tup, Index>> : std::true_type {};
}   // namespace detail

template<class TupIter>
struct is_tuple_iter : detail::is_tuple_iter_impl<std::decay_t<TupIter>> {};

template<class T>
inline constexpr bool is_tuple_iter_v = is_tuple_iter<T>::value;

template<class TupIter>
struct tuple {
    using type = typename std::decay_t<TupIter>::tuple_t;
};

template<class TupIter>
using tuple_t = typename tuple<TupIter>::type;

template<std::ptrdiff_t N, std::size_t Index, class Tup>
constexpr auto advance(const TupleIter<Tup, Index> &it) -> TupleIter<Tup, Index + N> {
    return it.template advance<N>();
}

// Easier to use in constant expressions
template<class TupIter1, class TupIter2,
         class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_iter_v<TupIter1> && is_tuple_iter_v<TupIter2>>>
constexpr size_t distance_v = TupIter2::index() - TupIter1::index();

// Performs template argument deduction
template<class TupIter1, class TupIter2>
constexpr auto distance([[maybe_unused]] const TupIter1 &it1, [[maybe_unused]] const TupIter2 &it2) {
    return distance_v<TupIter1, TupIter2>;
}

template<class T>
using begin_t = TupleIter<T, 0>;

template<class T>
using end_t = TupleIter<T, std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<T>>>;

template<class T>
constexpr auto begin([[maybe_unused]] T &tup) noexcept -> begin_t<T> {
    return begin_t<T>{tup};
}

template<class T>
constexpr auto end([[maybe_unused]] T &tup) noexcept -> end_t<T> {
    return end_t<T>{tup};
}

template<class TupIter, class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_iter_v<TupIter>>>
struct is_end :
        std::conditional_t<std::decay_t<TupIter>::index() == std::decay_t<TupIter>::size(),
                           std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

template<class TupIter>
constexpr bool is_end_v = is_end<TupIter>::value;
}   // namespace tuple_iter

#endif   // TUP_ITER_HPP
```

```cpp
// any_iter.hpp
#ifndef ANY_ITER_HPP
#define ANY_ITER_HPP

#include "tup_iter.hpp"
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

namespace tuple_iter {

// I decided to directly use a variant for this type and not wrap it in another class since this makes
// the integration in existing visitor code much easier.

namespace detail {
template<class Tuple, class T>
struct helper_t;

template<class Tuple, size_t... Indices>
struct helper_t<Tuple, std::index_sequence<Indices...>> {
    using type = std::variant<TupleIter<Tuple, Indices>...>;
};

template<class Tuple>
using default_index_sequence = std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::decay_t<Tuple>>>;

template<class Begin, class End, size_t... Indices>
struct span_sequence_impl :
        span_sequence_impl<decltype(++std::declval<Begin>()), End, Indices..., Begin::index()> {};

template<class Iter, size_t... Indices>
struct span_sequence_impl<Iter, Iter, Indices...> {
    using sequence = std::index_sequence<Indices...>;
};
}   // namespace detail

// Not including the past-the-end iterator per default. It is easier to handle it with std::optional in
// application code and do not have to handle it in visitors, since contrary to the others, it does not
// have the same methods. It is possible to provide an own sequence of indices that should be considered
template<class Tuple, class index_seq = detail::default_index_sequence<Tuple>>
using AnyIter = typename detail::helper_t<Tuple, index_seq>::type;

template<class Begin, class End>
using span_sequence =
    typename detail::span_sequence_impl<std::decay_t<Begin>, std::decay_t<End>>::sequence;

template<class TupleIter, class index_seq = detail::default_index_sequence<tuple_t<TupleIter>>,
         class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_iter_v<TupleIter>>>
constexpr auto make_any_iter(TupleIter &&it, index_seq /*unused*/ = {})
    -> AnyIter<tuple_t<TupleIter>, index_seq> {
    return AnyIter<tuple_t<TupleIter>, index_seq>{std::forward<TupleIter>(it)};
}

template<class Tuple, size_t N, class index_seq = detail::default_index_sequence<Tuple>,
         class = std::tuple_element<N, Tuple>>
constexpr auto make_any_iter(Tuple &&tup, std::integral_constant<size_t, N> /*unused*/ = {},
                             index_seq /*unused*/ = {}) -> AnyIter<Tuple, index_seq> {
    return AnyIter<Tuple, index_seq>{TupleIter<Tuple, N>{std::forward<Tuple>(tup)}};
}
}   // namespace tuple_iter

#endif   // ANY_ITER_HPP
```

```cpp
// tup_algo.hpp
#ifndef TUP_ALGO_HPP
#define TUP_ALGO_HPP

#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <optional>
#include "any_iter.hpp"

namespace tuple_iter {

// Type based find algorithm, only works on the types. Pred should be a class template that explicitly converts to bool.
template<template<class> class Pred, class Begin, class End>
constexpr auto find_type(Begin begin, End end) noexcept {
    if constexpr (begin == end) {
        return end;
    } else {
        if constexpr (Pred<typename Begin::value_t>()) {
            return begin;
        } else {
            return find_type<Pred>(++begin, end);
        }
    }
}

template<template<class> class Pred, class Begin, class End>
using find_type_t = decltype(find_type<Pred>(std::declval<Begin>(), std::declval<End>()));

// Value based find algorithm, can use both types and values in the tuple. Pred should be an object that can be called with each of the searched types.
template<class Pred, class Begin, class End, class Sequence = span_sequence<Begin, End>>
constexpr auto find_type_any(Begin begin, End end, Pred pred, Sequence seq = {}) noexcept
    -> std::optional<AnyIter<typename Begin::tuple_t, Sequence>> {
    if constexpr (begin == end) {
        return {};
    } else {
        if (pred(*begin)) {
            return {begin};
        } else {
            return find_type_any(++begin, end, pred, seq);
        }
    }
}

// Applies f on each element in the iterated range. f should be an object that is callable on each of the types in the range.
template<class Begin, class End, class Func>
constexpr auto for_each(Begin begin, End end, Func f) noexcept -> Func {
    if constexpr (begin == end) {
        return f;
    } else {
        f(*begin);
        return for_each(++begin, end, f);
    }
}

// Accumulates the iterated range in the form:
//   Op(...Op(Op(v, begin), ++begin), ..., end)
// Op should be an object that can be called appropriately.
template<class Begin, class End, class Val = typename Begin::value_t, class Op = std::plus<>>
constexpr auto accumulate(Begin begin, End end, Val v = {}, Op op = {}) noexcept {
    if constexpr (begin == end) {
        return v;
    } else {
        return accumulate(++begin, end, op(v, *begin), op);
    }
}

}   // namespace tuple_iter
#endif   // TUP_ALGO_HPP
```

````cpp
#include "any_iter.hpp"
#include "tup_algo.hpp"
#include "tup_iter.hpp"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace tuple_iter;

// Templated class that evaluates to true iff it is templated on cv char.
template<class Found>
struct StructFinder {
    constexpr explicit operator bool() {
        return std::is_same_v<std::remove_cv_t<Found>, char>;
    }
};

// Templated class that evaluates to true iff its template argument passed to its template template
// argument instantiates a true type

// Templated class that searches for the value of its data member.
template<class Val>
struct ValueFinder {
    template<class T, class = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<Val, T>>>
    constexpr auto operator()(T && /*unused*/) -> bool {
        return false;
    }

    constexpr auto operator()(const Val &v) -> bool {
        return v == searched;
    }

    Val searched;
};

template<class Val>
ValueFinder(Val)->ValueFinder<Val>;

auto main() -> int {
    std::tuple<int, const char, double> tup{1, 'A', 2.1};
    using tup_t = decltype(tup);

    end_t<tup_t> e{tup};
    auto a = --e;
    auto b = ++++begin(tup);
    TupleIter iter(tup, index_tag<1>);

    static_assert(e.index() == 3);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a), decltype(b)>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(a)::value_t, double>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<begin_t<tup_t>::value_t, std::tuple_element_t<0, tup_t>>);
    static_assert(distance_v<begin_t<tup_t>, end_t<tup_t>> == 3);
    static_assert(iter.index() == 1);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<begin_t<std::tuple<>>, end_t<std::tuple<>>>);

    // decltype(e)::value_t i = 5; // Good: Does not compile
    assert(*a == 2.1);

    auto any = make_any_iter(iter);
    auto any2 = make_any_iter(tup, index_tag<2>, std::index_sequence<2>{});
    assert(any.index() == 1);
    assert(any2.index() == 0);

    std::visit(
        [](auto &&first, auto &&second) { std::cout << *first << ' ' << *second << '\n'; }, any, any2);

    const char value{std::get<1>(any)};
    assert(value == std::get<1>(tup));
    static_assert(span_sequence<decltype(a), end_t<tup_t>>::size() == 1);
    static_assert(span_sequence<end_t<tup_t>, end_t<tup_t>>::size() == 0);

    using it_t = find_type_t<StructFinder, begin_t<tup_t>, end_t<tup_t>>;
    it_t it = find_type<StructFinder>(begin(tup), end(tup));
    std::cout << *it << '\n';

    using tup2_t = std::tuple<int, std::vector<int>, int, char, double>;
    using it2_t = find_type_t<std::is_integral, typename begin_t<tup2_t>::next_t, end_t<tup2_t>>;
    static_assert(it2_t::index() == 2);

    auto any_iter = *find_type_any(begin(tup), a, ValueFinder{1});
    static_assert(std::variant_size_v<decltype(any_iter)> == 2);
    assert(any_iter.index() == 0);

    // Should be type safe
    assert(!find_type_any(begin(tup), end(tup), ValueFinder<int>{'A'}));

    std::tuple numbers{1, 1.4, 3l, -7.123f, 'A'};

    auto sum1 = for_each(++begin(numbers), --end(numbers), [sum = 0.](auto v) mutable {
        std::cout << v << ", ";
        return sum += v;
    });
    auto sum2 = accumulate(++begin(numbers), --end(numbers));

    assert(sum1(0.) == sum2);
    std::cout << '\n' << sum2 << '\n';
}
```
````

Comment: I think it would help if there were more examples of why this is useful. For example, summing up the items of a tuple can already be done in standard C++: `std::apply( [](auto... v) { return (v + ...); }, numbers);` or with `std::visit` and a closure. How is this better than normal fold expressions, or a vector<any>?

Comment: I think the most interesting is `find_type_t` and maybe other algorithms on the types of a tuple. One is able search for a type, and not just an exact type, like with `std::get<T>` but following pretty arbitrary constraints, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59656224/find-a-tuple-in-a-tuple-of-tuples) inspired me for this project. I will add some examples what one can do with this. But mostly this is just an exercise for me and I am not that interested in the usefulness of the code but more the experience I gather by writing it and hopefully by other people commenting on it.

Comment: Hi n314159, it seems that you mistakenly post `tup_iter.hpp` twice when you meant to have `tup_iter.hpp` + `any_iter.hpp`. I have replaced the second code block with `any_iter.hpp` according to your GitHub repository. Feel free to roll back my edit if I am wrong!

Comment: @L.F. Thanks very much, yes I messed that a bit up.

Comment: @butt I added a further example for `find` and also changed the example for `accumulate` to show it is a bit more flexible than `std::apply`. But I agree, that most use-cases are a bit contrived. I think if I expand the algorithms a bit, there are interesting things to be done on types (i.e. splicing parts of two tuples together or tranforming a `tuple<a,b,c,d>` to `tuple<pair<a,b>, pair<c,d>` pretty easily) but that is not done right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great. Clean and readable code, following modern C++ programming practices. Good job!

Here are my suggestions on further improvements:

## Tag types

The point of tags is disambiguation. Instead of reusing `std::integral_constant<size_t, Index>`, I prefer to use a separate type:

```
template <std::size_t I>
struct index_type {
    explicit index_type() = default;
};
template <std::size_t I>
inline constexpr index_type<I> index{};
```

## About `std::conditional_t`

> ```
> // Helper for value_t since we cannot specialize a type alias directly and have to prevent the
> // instantiation of std::tuple_element_t<I, tuple_t> for the case of I == size() sinze then this
> // would not compile. Hence, we cannot simply use std::conditional.
> ```

We can.  Just a bit differently:

```
// somewhere
template <typename T>
struct type_identity {
    using type = T;
};

struct incomplete;
```

then

```
using decay_tuple_t = std::decay_t<tuple_t>;  // exposition only

using value_t = typename std::conditional_t<  // note: _t
    I < size(),
    std::tuple_element<Index, decay_tuple_t>, // note: no _t
    incomplete
>::type;                                      // note: ::type
using next_t = typename std::conditional_t<
    I < size(),
    TupleIter<tuple_t, Index + 1>,
    incomplete
>::type;
```

Think of why `_t` and `::type` are used at the same time.

## Comparison

Now, according to your logic, two `TupleIter`s are equal if and only if they are the same type.  We can already compare types with `is_same`, so I'd expect the `==` and `!=` operators to take the tuple into account as well.  I also prefer to define symmetrical operators as non-members, but that's unimportant in this case:

```
template <typename Tuple, std::size_t I>
constexpr auto operator==(const TupleIter<Tuple, I>& lhs, const TupleIter<Tuple, I>& rhs)
    -> decltype(lhs.get_tuple() == rhs.get_tuple()) // for SFINAE
{
    return lhs.get_tuple() == rhs.get_tuple();
}

template <typename Tuple, std::size_t I>
constexpr auto operator!=(const TupleIter<Tuple, I>& lhs, const TupleIter<Tuple, I>& rhs)
    -> decltype(lhs == rhs)
{
    return !(lhs == rhs);
}
```

## `++` and `--`

> ```
> // These seem a bit weird since they are const de-/increment operators. But we cannot implement
> // operator+(int inc) as one would normally do it, since inc had to be a constant expression. So
> // this seems like the best way to do this. Furthermore it is actually similar to normal iterators,
> // since for them the following would be equivalent:
> //      ++it;       AND       it = ++it;
> // So reassigning the return value is not that weird.
> ```

(You actually cannot reassign because the type changes.)

One sec ... you can implement this:

```
auto new_iter = it + incr<5>;
```

or even

```
using namespace tuple_iter::literals;
auto new_iter = it + 5_i;
```

(Let's pray that `it + 5` will become implementable in a future standard.)

## `distance`

Don't forget you can implement `iter1 - iter2`.

## `is_end`

This is convoluted:

> ```
> template<class TupIter, class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_iter_v<TupIter>>>
> struct is_end :
>         std::conditional_t<std::decay_t<TupIter>::index() == std::decay_t<TupIter>::size(),
>                            std::true_type, std::false_type> {};
> ```

Consider:

```
template <class TupIter, class = std::enable_if_t<is_tuple_iter_v<TupIter>>>
struct is_end :
        std::bool_constant<std::decay_t<TupIter>::index() == std::decay_t<TupIter>::size()> {};
```

Also, `is_end` is SFINAE-friendly but `is_end_v` issues hard errors.

## `if else if`

> ```
> // Type based find algorithm, only works on the types. Pred should be a class template that explicitly converts to bool.
> template<template<class> class Pred, class Begin, class End>
> constexpr auto find_type(Begin begin, End end) noexcept {
>     if constexpr (begin == end) {
>         return end;
>     } else {
>         if constexpr (Pred<typename Begin::value_t>()) {
>             return begin;
>         } else {
>             return find_type<Pred>(++begin, end);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

We can use `else if` to avoid one level of indentation:

```
template <template <class> class Pred, class Begin, class End>
constexpr auto find_type(Begin begin, End end) noexcept
{
    if constexpr (begin == end) {
        return end;
    } else if constexpr (Pred<typename Begin::value_t>()) {
        return begin;
    } else {
        return find_type<Pred>(++begin, end);
    }
}
```

You add a level of recursion for every element in the tuple.

## Conversion to `bool`

The `operator bool` is a bit weird to me.  `if (iter)`?  I guess a named function like `.is_valid()` may be clearer.

## Small issues

- Macro names like `TUP_ITER_HPP` are common and easy to clash. I would append a random sequence of characters: `TUP_ITER_HPP_Hfod7C3iAQ` (generated with [Random String Generator](https://www.random.org/strings/?num=1&len=10&digits=on&upperalpha=on&loweralpha=on&format=html) on random.org).
- `size_t` should be `std::size_t`, and `#include <cstddef>` is missing.

## Stylistic (subjective)

The points below are purely subjective and can be ignored if they contradict with your established style guidelines.

- I don't really like the always-trailing-return style.  I prefer `static constexpr std::size_t size() noexcept`.  This is especially distracting: `auto main() -> int`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your in-depth-analysis. I will consider your comments carefully.

Comment: Your comments were very helpful, thanks again. I will be reworking my code to include them. The only thing I am still unsure about is the comparison. I see your reasoning, but I will at least add SFINAE s.t. the code still compiles when the tuple is not equality comparable (i.e. deactivate `operator==`). And in my opinion, it would be cleaner if the `operator==` only takes really comparable types if it works with the values (so that comparing between different TupleIters will not compile).

Comment: @n314159 I see your point. Instead of accepting incompatible types and always returning `false`, you argue that it's less misleading to disable it in the first place, right? I agree. I'll update my code.

Comment: @n314159 (btw, don't declare `operator==` as a member function. It breaks SFINAE.)